# How to create line breaks in xml using java

Tags: java, xml, line-breaks, setattribute

I want to create an xml file with line breaks, looking somewhat like this:

```
<Instrument currencyId="THB"
disabledCount="0"
hasBeenEnabledOnce="TRUE"
</Instrument>
```

Using this code I got close but all attributes seems to be end up on the same row:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Instrument");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

Instrument.setAttribute("currencyId", "THB");
Instrument.setAttribute("disabledCount", "0");
Instrument.setAttribute("hasBeenEnabledOnce", "TRUE");

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

I get the following result:

```
<Instrument currencyId="THB" disabledCount="0" hasBeenEnabledOnce="TRUE"
```

How can I add linebreaks between the attributes??

just a slight notice, I thought that transformer.setOutputProperies could solve the problem, by searching for similar problems I ended up with "OutputKeys.INDENT", "yes", and the indent-amount -> "4". But nothing's changed.
Doesnt matter if I open the file in notepad++ or as a webpage.

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. Please correct it (looks like a missing ">" but only you can know)

Comment: That was not really my question but yeah, there is a ">" missing after "TRUE", should be there, I just missed it when copying from my code.
My question on the other hand is about, if its possible to make a line break between "currencyId="THB"" and "disabledCount="0"" so that it looks like the intended code above?

Comment: It wasn't clear where you want the end tag, or whether you wish to use the "/>" construct or whether there was content which might have been omitted. In general formatting inside start tags is normally dependent on your toolchain - you may have to subclass the serialization class(es)